# How to do JavaMail in EE6 right?

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, java-ee-6, jakarta-mail, quartz-scheduler

I was wondering how other's do their mailing stuff and what is you opinion about best practices. When I think about how the mailing stuff can be done, I can only think of one solution that can be realized with different technologies in different ways.

1. Make the mail somehow persistent (save in DB, send over JMS)
2. Continuously check(using a scheduler to fetch from DB or via JMS) for new mails that haven't been successfully sent yet and try to send them, when an error occurs, try again later

The other option which hopefully nobody uses without a really good reason, would be to send the mail within the the business logic and may cause a transaction to fail (or take very long when retrying to send the mail for a specific set of times) because the mail couldn't be sent.

In a different project I have seen a standalone mail sender app, that continuously queries the DB and sends emails based on criterias like current time etc.

So what do you think is a good solution, or what do you actually use in your projects? I wasn't able to find any realworld examples of that via google, maybe I didn't search enough, but if so, please share your resources with me!

**EDIT**
To define the "right way" I would like to add some requirements:

- Mails must be persistent, editable, resendable
- Based on some criteria mails can be sent at a specific time
- The solution should scale horizontal

EE6 offers EJB with TimerService and Async-operations. By asking for the "right way" for EE6 environments I would like to know how mailing is supposed to be used/implemented for such standard requirements.

There are some articles at the oracle sites showing the usage of the mail session in an @Async EJB method, but that usage sounds somehow wrong. Should I use the timer service to retry sending mails? Should I persist mails to a DB and use an interval timer to fetch and try to send them? Should I move the sending of the mails outside of the app?

I would like to know what solutions others use and hear opinions about what might be a better or worse solution for such (hopefully not only for me)common requirements.

Comment: @Tichodroma The problem is how to transfer/send mails to receivers in EE6 the "right way"?

Answer (score 2):

In our project we use Quartz scheduler to run the job.Before job is scheduled to send the email,message is composed and different parts of the email like subject,body, recipients are stored in the database.
when quartz jobs runs and if it is able to send email successfully,sent_flg of the message will be set to SENT.
If failed,quartz job is scheduled to run again after some time with the same params.
It would try for certain no of times,before it gives up.
There is a screen as well where the admin can resend the messages that are failed in case he wants to sent it.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution, I was thinking of something similar!

Answer (score 1):

One option is to just install an [MTA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent), likely dedicated to this purpose, e.g. sendmail for Linux.  I'd have it running on the same node(s) as my (Java) applications.  Especially if running locally, this server should be "guaranteed" to be available.  Just let the application server send the mail using this as the SMTP server.  At that point, it's practically "fire & forget", and just as good as something like JMS.  A properly configured MTA will immediately accept the message (allowing the JVM to continue on its way) - and spend time on its own threads attempting to resend any messages, etc.

The only real disadvantage of this approach is that you won't be able to easily inspect back from Java (without parsing log files, etc.) as to the actual progress of a given email - but even then, email is never guaranteed, as it may be rejected / dropped by any upstream mail server, or the receiving client.

Comment: Ok so you are actually using this setup in production environments? That sounds a bit unflexible to me. Would you mind adding some advantages of this solution over a DB or JMS solution?

Comment: @ChristianBeikov - yes, and actually, exclusively at current.  What do you see as inflexible?

Comment: I think that it might be hard to alter emails and resend them based on user requests. I also wonder if you could specify something like, "Mails of type X should not be sent on weekends". The customers of a project I worked on earlier had such requirements and I don't want to be forced to migrate a solution at a later time because of such requirements.

Comment: @ChristianBeikov - My original answer was primarily from a performance perspective.  To address these types of requirements, I'd do this: "In a different project I have seen a standalone mail sender app, that continuously queries the DB and sends emails based on criterias like current time etc." - potentially combined with my above answer.